# Is it OK to work on a branch that was created by someone else?

Tags: git, merge, branch

### Background:

I'm working on a project using GitHub and I am supervised by senior developers who sometimes push some additional code to my repository.

Suppose, they added a new branch called `tests` to the repository. The `tests` branch is adding some template files I have to work on. When I'm done, I should merge these files with the `master` branch.

## Doubts:

Should I:

- work on the `tests` branch or
- create my own branch (like `my-tests` or `tests-preparation`) and merge it with the `master` after the work is done?

The point is that my supervisors might push some changes to the `tests` branch and I want to avoid conflicts of my code and their code. On the other hand, I don't want to create unnecessary branches with troublesome names.

What is the best practice in such a situation?

Comment: the best practice is to pick up your phone and discuss it with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is also there to manage conflicts. So pushing in the same branch isn't supposed to be a real problem.

If the thing you don't want them to handle conflicts, maybe you could work in another branch.

Is it necessary that your branch is on the server? You could also work in a local branch that you never push to origin. And from time to time merge `tests`.